# AS3 - starting function at end of another function

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an AS3 function that I need to end with calling another function.

```
function receiveText(value:String):void {
        channel.stop();
        channel2.stop();
        songPosition = 0;
        var soundFile2:URLRequest = new URLRequest(jsVariableValue2);
        var myMusic2:Sound = new Sound();  //Intstantation
        myMusic2.load(soundFile2, myContext);
```

I need to call this playMusic function at the end of it in order to start playing the audio track

```
function playMusic(evt:Event):void
{
    if (soundFile2exist == "noValue")
    {
        channel = myMusic.play(songPosition);
    }
    else
    {
    channel = myMusic.play(songPosition);
    channel2 = myMusic2.play(channel.position);
    }
    myTimer.start();
    btnPlay.mouseEnabled = false;
    trace (soundFile2exist);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Any errors?

Comment: No errors, I'm just sort of new to AS3.  I'm not sure how I would tell playMusic to start after receiveText is finished running.  It asks for an argument if I end with playMusic();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "run" another function you just call the function name:

```
playMusic();
```

In your case you have a function (method) that require a return of an Event. I´m not sure why you have that. Remove it or just pass a null (playMusic(null);) into the function. If the music does not play you will have to provide us more code.